Javascript to emit Windows-Key H from Acrobat Pro Text Field?
I'm helping a friend with less experience than my own /-;.
Using Windows 10 and Acrobat-Pro V10 (rolling release).
We would like to use Acrobat-Pro (or Nitro-Pro) Text Field's "Run Javascript" on "Mouse Enter" so that the action is as if the "Windows-Key H" keyboard combination is emitted in a way that it will launch the Windows Dictation Subsystem when a user clicks into a Text Field box.
So please note, this is a Javascript code inside of Acrobat-Pro. I'm not sure what manages the execution environment for the Javascript; the App, or does it "talk" with the underlying OS (Windows 10+ in this use case).
Currently, A user can click into a Text Field in Acrobat Pro and manually press the Windows-Key H combination and the dictation system is available.
We would like to go beyond that, so the user only needs to click in the Text Field box, and the dictation service starts.
Here is how far I have gotten in my research
Edit
Added a Text Field to a blank document. Right-Clicked and Selected Properties. Selected the Actions tag. Selected Trigger = 'Mouse Enter and Action = 'Run a Javascript. Pasted the below code.
Note, Also tried Mouse Up, per the Apress book "Enhancing Adobe Acrobat Forms With Javascript"
    function simulateKeyPress(key, modifiers) {
        const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
            key: key,
            ctrlKey: modifiers.includes('Control'),
            shiftKey: modifiers.includes('Shift'),
            altKey: modifiers.includes('Alt'),
            metaKey: modifiers.includes('Meta')
        });
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    function simulateWindowsKeyH() {
        simulateKeyPress('h', ['Meta']);
    }

    // Simulate the "Windows-key H" combination
    simulateWindowsKeyH();

I also found a much simpler version
    var keyCombo =  "[H";
    console.log(keyCombo);

(Edit) which would be my preferred solution and resonates with the technology I'm familar with.
(Both of these codes snips were provided by an AI system, which seemed to "understand" the question).
I tried it with, and without <script> and curly brace wrappers, but to no output or error messages.
In all testing cases, I am not getting any feedback from Windows or Acrobat-Pro, especially disappointing when using the 'Execute' button in the JavaScript Editor, which I assume is to allow for in-line development and testing of code.
Extra thoughts:
A. I have tried wrapping the complete code set with curly braces, i.e. { ... code set .... }
B. From a separate credible source, I am assuming I don't need <script> ... </script> wrapping tags. Correct?
C. Is there some logging system I can look at for error messages?
Any advice, comments etc are welcome.
Thanks

@morganney : sorry, I didn't mean to drive you away. The friend I'm helping has limited availability and we focused on trying to find the console. Internet search brings up contradictory instructions. The best we have found was a temp console attached to a code display. where the only thing that works is a cursor position "report" at the bottom left o the input box. No errors reported. I was assuming there is a way to have a console open all the time, like a web browser inspector panel. We did activate debugging and the debuger (Don't have the details avail right now). Thanks for any help.

Using the debugger/debugging was super awkward and we're undoubtedly doing it wrong. We had to create code from Text Field -> Properties -> JavaScript (tab), Save that. Exit the Form creation and goto the debugger, navigate (the DOM?) to the form Text Field object and then "run" it from there. No action/output, no error msgs. Stuck between documenting what is failing, and scrambling to  find new things to try (that also fail) ) )-; ..

This is laughably impossible, for security reasons. If it was possible for javascript to use keyboard shortcuts or send commands to other programs, then what would stop javascript from typing "Windows+R"->"cmd"->"Enter"->"format c:\" ? Javascript can't access programs outside its little browser sandbox, and if it could, it'd be a major security flaw that would get patched immediately.

Have you looked into the SpeechRecognition API instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#examples

@EliezerBerlin : Thanks for the reference. I don't see how this would be an easy fit with Adobe Acrobat Pro and the resulting PDF files that we would have for user input. Am I missing something? Tnx!

I mean, it's the JavaScript method of speech-to-text. But no, like you say, it's probably not going to achieve your goals easily. When I was looking at it, it looked frightfully complicated.

If it's for your friend's personal use, I suspect a third-party program like autohotkey would be way, way, way simpler, but autohotkey would be a separate program, not built into the PDF.

Some googling has turned up this: https://blog.developer.adobe.com/adding-voice-control-to-your-documents-8a01c5d35246 A blog post from Adobe about using your voice to control your PDFs via javascript.

@EliezerBerlin : Wow, not sure how we missed that. It looks worth further investigation. Thanks!

As @eliezer-berlin already mentioned, JavaScript can't really dispatch physical keypresses outside of browsers or other sandboxed environments (Acrobat, for example!). The script is isolated from the rest of the system, preventing it from performing actions that could affect the operating system (or other applications). This is crucial for security, as scripts should not perform any unauthorized actions.
For understanding KeyboardEvent objects better, I would highly recommend exploring the MDN Web Docs, or looking for examples of how it simulates key events online.
Does it mean it's over, and nothing can be done...? In your case, I don't think so. You might want to look at this related question. Exploring alternative methods for enabling speech dictation using JS, instead of opening the Windows Dictation Subsystem directly, could provide you with some viable solutions. Unfortunately I can't help you further with that. Best of luck!

Thanks for the additional information. Are you saying with "understanding KeyboardEvent objects better", that this will help me understand why it can NEVER work, or that it may contain a possible solution?

@shelter "understanding KeyobardEvent objects better" to learn the intended usecases and understand why it is, indeed, impossible, and will never work. The only possible solution I can see is to find an alternative for speech2text (or any other purpose for which you wanted to use the Windows Dictation system) in JavaScript, which you could use from within Acrobat
